# « J'ai voulu concis » : fautif ou non ?

Tags: expressions, usage, verbes

Dans un dossier de postulation j'ai rencontré la phrase :

> Pour en faciliter la lecture, ce document est structuré en cinq chapitres que j'ai voulu concis.

En googlant, je ne trouve pas quelque part l'expression *que j'ai voulu concis*. Est-elle erronée ou a-t-elle une connotation qui m'échapperait ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il n'y a pas d'erreur ; c'est un usage de « vouloir » assez courant, que l'on trouve au TLFi ;

> [Avec un attribut du compl. d'obj. dir.] Souhaiter avoir, proposer une chose qui présente certaines qualités. Vouloir un steack saignant. La merluche se réduit en une espèce de crème. Si vous la voulez verte, vous pilez des épinards dont vous joignez le suc (Gdes heures cuis. fr., Grimod de la Reynière, 1838, p. 159):
>   Cet art, il le veut conforme à ce qu'il appelle la réalité: c'est pourquoi il garde la nostalgie de certains aspects du réalisme. Il le veut agréable à sa sensibilité, brillant, luisant et quelque peu voluptueux...
>   CASSOU, Arts plast. contemp., 1960, p. 16.

Il y a cependant une erreur dans l'accord du participe passé parce que le COD est placé avant : « que j'ai voulu**s** concis ».

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas une faute, c'est juste que ce style de formulation est assez peu répandu.

On entendrait plus régulièrement ce genre de phrase :

> Pour en faciliter la lecture, ce document est structuré en cinq chapitres que j'ai voulu **rendre plus concis**.

Ce qui signifie, ici, *le résumer pour en rendre la lecture plus accessible*

Comment: C'est très courant, au contraire : « Cette porte, je la veux fermée. », « Comment voulez-vous ce steak ? Je le voudrais saignant. »,…

Answer (score 1):

La phrase est correcte.
Ce n'est pas une expression proprement dite mais juste l'adjectif "Concis" utilisé ici et signifiant "bref" ou "de forme réduite".

Le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/concis) en donne la définition: "Qui est réduit à l'essentiel et l'exprime en peu de mots".

Comment: Vous dites "une expression proprement dite". Qu'est-ce que vous voulez dire avec cela ?

Comment: @dimitris effectivement ce genre d'expression n'est pas courant, voici un autre exemple : "J'ai commandé 5 chaises que j'ai voulu bleu", ce qui signifie "J'ai commandé 5 chaises, j'ai voulu qu'elles soient bleu". Ce qui donne pour la question de départ : "ce document est structuré en cinq chapitres, j'ai voulu qu'ils soient concis".

Comment: Merci ! Donc, l'auteur de ce dossier possède-t-il un bon niveau du français (étant donné qu'il n'est pas locuteur natif), n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Par expression, j'entends plusieurs termes qui, juxtaposés, change leur sens premier comme "décrocher la lune"  ou "faire le pont".  L'exemple qui nous interesse ("... concis"), n'est pas une expression de ce type.

Comment: @RémiHenry *...que j'ai voulu**es** bleu**es***

Comment: @ jlliagre merci pour cette correction